# How I can make a gradient between 2 or more ellipses with GD?

Tags: php, image, gd, ellipse

How I can make a gradient between 2 or more ellipses with GD?

The following is an ellipse:

```
<?php

header( "Content-type: image/gif" );

$imagen = imagecreatefrompng('tras.png');


$morado = array( 'r' => 186, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 255 );
$amarillo = array( 'r' => 255, 'g' => 220, 'b' => 0 );

$pasos = 2000;

$incr_r = ( $amarillo['r'] - $morado['r'] ) / $pasos;
$incr_g = ( $amarillo['g'] - $morado['g'] ) / $pasos;
$incr_b = ( $amarillo['b'] - $morado['b'] ) / $pasos;

$cx = imagesx( $imagen ) / 3;
$cy = imagesy( $imagen ) / 3;

$ancho = 240;
$alto = 140;

$incr_x = $ancho / $pasos;
$incr_y = $alto / $pasos;

$r = $morado['r'];
$g = $morado['g'];
$b = $morado['b'];

for( $i = 0; $i < $pasos; $i++ ){
$color = imagecolorallocate( $imagen, $r, $g, $b );
imagefilledellipse( $imagen, $cx, $cy, $ancho, $alto, $color );
imagefilledellipse( $imagen, $ñ, $k, $ancho, $alto, $color );

$r += $incr_r;
$g += $incr_g;
$b += $incr_b;

$ancho -= $incr_x;
$alto -= $incr_y;
}

imagegif( $imagen );

imagedestroy( $imagen );

?>
```

Model...
This...
http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/11/capturazv.png
without cutting

Comment: Could you show us a mockup image of what you want?

Comment: I just want two ellipses, and that between these two have a gradient. I have no model.

Comment: I can't really understand what you mean by "ellipses with a gradient in between", can you show us a mock-up of what you want?

Comment: This...
http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/11/capturazv.png
without cutting

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the class [here](http://planetozh.com/blog/my-projects/images-php-gd-gradient-fill/) will help you, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but not exactly what I need.